# What happens when charging a pair of AA NiMH batteries where one might be emptier than the other?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nimh

When there are multiple AA NiMH batteries that have been stored some time after being charged (so that they will be at hand if needed) and I want to charge them a little more, there appears a problem in that some might have been sitting for a longer time than others and therefore are more depleted.

This in itself is not a problem, but since my charger only charges pairs of batteries, that means that I'd be charging a pair where one might be fuller, and the other emptier. What would happen in that case? I'm guessing one of these three options.

Which one is correct, or are they all wrong?

1. The charger will charge until the fuller one is full and stop, leaving the emptier one partly empty. That's not great, but it's not too bad.
2. The charger will charge till the emptier one is full, harming the fuller one. That's not good.
3. The emptier one will charge faster catching up to the fuller one and all will be well.

Anecdotal evidence seems to be pointing at 2, though I expected 1. (3 seems the least likely.)

So which one (or none) is it?

Comment: depends on the design of the charger

Comment: Unbalanced batteries in series are bad, one can dissipate power if undercharged. That being said it doesn't need to be perfect

Comment: I will edit this to make it site suitable "later" and reopen. It can be an excellent question if targeted more generally at ensuring NiMH cells are managed and rehabilitated acceptably. Unbalanced charging is undesirable.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Thank you.